# How can display format of text jquery editor?

Tags: php, html, jquery-plugins

I using a jquery editor:
Save content of editor to database:

```
<b>Sim dep la gi</b><p><i><span style="color:rgb(255,0,0);">Sim dep la sim co nhung con so hop voi tuoi cua ban.</span></i><br></p><p><br></p>
```

I display this text to html:

```
<table  >
    <tr>
        <td >
            <p   style="font-weight: bold;"><%$Baiviets[0].title%></p>
            <%$Baiviets[0].contents%>

        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Result it still display on web:

```
<b>Sim dep la gi</b><p><i><span style="color:rgb(255,0,0);">Sim dep la sim co nhung con so hop voi tuoi cua ban.</span></i><br></p><p><br></p>
```

How can convert tag(`<b>,<p>,<i>,...`) to format when display on web?

Comment: Maybe use `htmlentities()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: i had try change to :   <%echo htmlentities($Baiviets[0].contents, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8")%>, but it occur error. htmlentities() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given

Comment: Which error? (15 characters....)

Comment: htmlentities() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given